# Hexadecimal NCR characters doesn't work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, hex, decimal, special-characters, ncr

For a web page  need some special characters (like ones bellow) that I found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

[image: Decimal NCRs]

[Converted](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) Decimal NCR values works fine in FF, Safari and Chrome. But not on IE where I get strange square character. Page is UTF8 encoded.

For example this is the code for one character:

[image]

This is what I get on Safari, FF and Chrome:

[image]

And this is on IE8:

[image]

Could please someone explains why this does not work in IE?

Comment: Probably because the IE you're using doesn't have a font that includes those letters?

Comment: Please post the source code you are using as well as the HTTP headers (or a URL of the page). Please specify the IE version used. There’s something odd going on here, unless you are using a very old version of IE (on a different computer?).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I've just added an example to the question. I've tested this code on IE8.

Comment: @BorutTomazin, please check your example. The reference `&#8675;` denotes U+21E3 DOWNWARDS DASHED ARROW “⇣”, so how would any browser render it as some kind of angular bracket?

Comment: You are right. I've made a mistake. Example code is now changed. Please take a look...

Comment: Can anyone get me an answer?